# BigQuery Storage Write API calls not logged to Audit logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-bigquery-storage-api

I'm trying to create a Cloud Function that is called when new rows are written to a BigQuery table using the Storage Write API (it's the Firebase Crashlytics to BigQuery stream).

However, the Cloud Function is never triggered. I checked the Audit Logs (which, I believe, is used to trigger the function) for [BigQueryWrite](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/rpc/google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1#bigquerywrite) entry but there is no such entry.

Is there any particular setting that needs to be enabled for it to be logged?

Comment: Does this [link](https://medium.com/@rhimanshu86/event-driven-workflows-in-bigquery-cloud-function-aaa426caf291) help you?

Comment: @kiranmathew That post is indeed talking about exactly what I want to do. However, the author is using `InsertJob` (which is working for me as well) whereas I want to listen to `AppendRows`.

Comment: Could you confirm that data is appended correctly when using the AppendRows method?